# Best way to create a property of an association in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities

I have a node Theater, and a node Movie, and a Theater can have X movies and for each movie at that specific theater there are Y showtimes. How can I set up the property "showtimes" of the association of Theater to Movie within Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection):

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.

You can then create:

- a content type Movie. You could have fields like a Poster image field, Title, Cast, synopsis, and then a **Showtimes** *field collection*.
- Then have a content type Theater. Which is a theater. It can have fields like geolocation, a picture of the building, a description, hours of operation, etc.
- Then your Showtimes field collection is itself a multi-value field which contains 2 fields: an entityreference to a Theater, and then a multi-value collection of times (maybe look at event module).

Using Views you should be able to list movies, Theaters and their movies, Movies at a certain time -- etc.

How to integrate this all into the [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module or something ... I leave this as an exercise for you.

I don't guarentee this is the best way to build the relationships between data you want. Another alternative to field collection and even the entities could be the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module.

**EDIT:**

If you want to easily create like a Theater that doesn't exist yet for a Movie (when making a movie entry) look at the [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third entity type, let's call it Showtime, that would have the following fields:

- Reference to a Theater
- Reference to a Movie
- Time

That way, Movies won't be linked to Theaters directly, but via Showtime nodes.

Comment: Thank you, but this answer represents a relationship, not a property of a relationship.